# How to develop the application for Window Surface RT?

Tags: microsoft-surface

I want to know What are all the sdk's available to develop application for Window surface RT?
Does Surface SDK will support all the tablets having Windows RT OS Installed?

Comment: Windows RT is Windows RT. The only supported applications are Windows Store Applications. You need to do some research on the subject.  There isn't a "Surface SDK"

Comment: There *IS* a "Surface SDK": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727815.aspx

Comment: For those not understanding, the "Surface SDK" linked here is not for Windows RT. It's for the older Microsoft Surface table, not the new tablet computer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make "Modern" apps. That is the tile-based applications that work only on Windows RT, you can just head over to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516

That should give you all the information you need. And yes, if you create a Modern App, it will work on Windows RT, and Pro. The best way to distribute this is to sell it on the Windows 8 store. Good luck.

Comment: I had to remove the comment about these kinds of questions being better at Stack Overflow. At the moment, it's much too vague (broad?) or lacks principal research effort, so it'd very likely be closed there as well.

Comment: True. But the type of question is better asked at SO. This is/was a programming related question, although it was very broad, and I am not surprised that it was closed.